# Подключение Firebase messaging к приложению

Tags: android, firebase, push-уведомления, push

Добрый день! Мне необходимо подключить firebase-messaging к своему приложению, реализую всё как написано  [в документации](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/start/)

И по вот этому [уроку](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlzcXlOatCo)

При проверки на подключение получаю вот такое сообщение

```
Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.
```

Я синхронизировал, я пересобирал и проверил все зависимости, но почему-то проблема не решается.

В gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.runtest.aplication"
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 16
        versionName "2"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                debuggable false
            }
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

и тут

```
    dependencies {
    //    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'

}
```

В чём может быть проблема? Заранее большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Где-то в настройках студии можно для градла прописать --stacktrace --debug и видеть более подробную инфу об ошибке

Comment: И да, кстати - Firebase перестанет быть бесплатным через 3 дня

Comment: добавил вот этот параметр --stacktrace --debug, перегрузил IDE? но ничего не поменялось, так же при нажатии на кнопку проверки соединения с firebase Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, у меня есть пара дней чтобы всё доделать и запустить пуш рассылку:) Потом буду разбираться как делать без firebase, сейчас пока больше учусь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы плагин не подключили

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Эта строчка должна быть ниже раздела `dependencies`

Вот так

```
   dependencies {
//    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Спасибо, но плагин был подключён, я всё делаю по документации, но почему-то не получается.

Comment: в общем, проблема была в IDE, кнопка проверки подключения к сервису не корректно работает, я собрал приложение, установил на телефон и проверил -- заработало! Все спасибо за помощь!